# Why can't NTFY authenticate with MS Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, smtp

First and foremost, Microsoft documentation advises [these details](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040) for SMTP with outlook. I use this fine with other services.

- **SMTP server name:** smtp-mail.outlook.com
- **SMTP port:** 587
- **SMTP encryption:** STARTTLS

Furthermore, NTFY advises that [SMTP and STARTTLS are supported](https://docs.ntfy.sh/config/?h=email#e-mail-notifications).

> "As of today, only SMTP servers with PLAIN auth and STARTLS are supported."

However, when I attempt to configure this via the `/etc/ntfy/server.yml` file, it does not work.
Notice two errors from logs below:

```
### smtp-mail.outlook.com:587
{"time":"2024-02-08T22:33:56.559Z","level":"WARN","message":"Unable to send email to cencored@cencored.com: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type [CY4PR0501MB3908.namprd05.prod.outlook.com 2024-02-08T22:33:51.710Z 08DC255743C7]","email":"cencored@cencored.com","error":"504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type [CY4PR0501MB3908.namprd05.prod.outlook.com 2024-02-08T22:33:51.710Z 08DC25520C743C70]","message_body_size":9,"message_event":"message","message_id":"4qmF5LaJcSpv","message_sender":"172.25.0.1","message_time":1707431626,"message_user":"u_U5MeBhxJuu","tag":"email","topic":"test-expiry-notifications","user_id":"u_U5MeBhxJuu","user_name":"cwood","visitor_auth_limiter_limit":0.016666666666666666,"visitor_auth_limiter_tokens":30,"visitor_emails":2,"visitor_emails_limit":24,"visitor_emails_remaining":22,"visitor_id":"ip:172.25.0.1","visitor_ip":"172.25.0.1","visitor_messages":2,"visitor_messages_limit":17280,"visitor_messages_remaining":17278,"visitor_request_limiter_limit":0.2,"visitor_request_limiter_tokens":57.056149986399994,"visitor_seen":"2024-02-08T22:33:52.477Z"}

### smtp-legacy.office365.com:587
{"time":"2024-02-08T23:16:18.697Z","level":"WARN","message":"Unable to send email to cencored@cencored.com: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type [CY4PR0501.prod.exchangelabs.com 2024-02-08T23:16:13.824Z 08DC27850D59]","email":"cencored@cencored.com","error":"504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type [CY4PR0501.prod.exchangelabs.com 2024-02-08T23:16:13.824Z 08DC278511F0D59E]","message_body_size":9,"message_event":"message","message_id":"H0c2IFiqomiR","message_sender":"172.26.0.1","message_time":1707434168,"message_user":"u_U5MeBhxJuu","tag":"email","topic":"test-expiry-notifications","visitor_auth_limiter_limit":0.016666666666666666,"visitor_auth_limiter_tokens":30,"visitor_emails":1,"visitor_emails_limit":24,"visitor_emails_remaining":23,"visitor_id":"ip:172.26.0.1","visitor_ip":"172.26.0.1","visitor_messages":1,"visitor_messages_limit":17280,"visitor_messages_remaining":17279,"visitor_request_limiter_limit":0.2,"visitor_request_limiter_tokens":60,"visitor_seen":"2024-02-08T23:16:09.983Z"}
```

At first I attempted to connect as described in Microsofts documentation:

```
# /etc/ntfy/server.yml

smtp-sender-addr: "smtp-mail.outlook.com:587"
smtp-sender-from: "alias@cencored.com"
smtp-sender-pass: "cencored"
smtp-sender-user: "cencored@cencored.com"
```

After that, I attempted using the legacy SMTP endpoint as documented [here](https://office365itpros.com/2021/08/19/exchange-online-to-introduce-legacy-smtp-endpoint-in-2022/).

```
smtp-sender-addr: "smtp-legacy.office365.com:587"
```

In either case it fails with the errors provided.